# webpack-dev-server hot reloading partially works under Windows 8

Tags: windows, vim, webpack

So I have very basic example set up under Windows 8 following the tutorial from 
http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

Everything is ok except the hot reloading feature. When I edit the source files for the demo in a Notepad - hot reloading works. But when I am trying to use vim from the console emulator like MINGW64 or CMDER there hot reloading is not being triggered.

Any clues how to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a known issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/155